# SciRuby error failed to build gem native extension

Tags: macos, sciruby

I was installing SciRuby in my macbook(OSX). I had this similar issues when installing SciRuby in another Ubuntu laptop which was fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961227/failed-to-install-sciruby).

```
~ gem install sciruby-full
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sciruby-full:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160318-8616-cy3gbi.rb extconf.rb
checking for apparent GNU g++ binary with C++0x/C++11 support... 4.9
using C++ standard... c++11
g++ reports version... gcc49
checking for main() in -lclapack... yes
checking for main() in -llapack... yes
checking for main() in -lcblas... yes
checking for main() in -latlas... no
checking for atlas/cblas.h... no
checking for cblas.h... no
checking for clapack.h... no
checking for clapack_dgetrf() in atlas/clapack.h... no
checking for clapack_dgetri() in atlas/clapack.h... no
checking for dgesvd_() in clapack.h... no
checking for cblas_dgemm() in cblas.h... no
creating nmatrix_config.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling nmatrix.cpp
In file included from nmatrix.cpp:59:0:
math/math.h:128:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:128:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:128:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:134:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:134:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:134:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:140:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:140:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:140:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::syrk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = float]':
math/math.h:142:70: error: 'cblas_ssyrk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_ssyrk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, *alpha, A, lda, *beta, C, ldc);
                                                                      ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:146:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:146:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:146:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::syrk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = double]':
math/math.h:148:70: error: 'cblas_dsyrk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_dsyrk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, *alpha, A, lda, *beta, C, ldc);
                                                                      ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:152:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:152:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:152:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::syrk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<float>]':
math/math.h:154:68: error: 'cblas_csyrk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_csyrk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, alpha, A, lda, beta, C, ldc);
                                                                    ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:158:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:158:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:158:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void syrk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::syrk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<double>]':
math/math.h:160:68: error: 'cblas_zsyrk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_zsyrk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, alpha, A, lda, beta, C, ldc);
                                                                    ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:165:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:165:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:165:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::herk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<float>]':
math/math.h:167:74: error: 'cblas_cherk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_cherk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, alpha->r, A, lda, beta->r, C, ldc);
                                                                          ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:171:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                             ^
math/math.h:171:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:171:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
 inline void herk(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE Trans, const int N,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::herk(int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, const DType*, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<double>]':
math/math.h:173:74: error: 'cblas_zherk' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_zherk(Order, Uplo, Trans, N, K, alpha->r, A, lda, beta->r, C, ldc);
                                                                          ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:178:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                             ^
math/math.h:178:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_SIDE' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:178:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:179:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const DType* alpha,
                             ^
math/math.h:179:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_DIAG' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const DType* alpha,
                                                            ^
math/math.h:185:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                             ^
math/math.h:185:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_SIDE' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:185:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:186:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const float* alpha,
                             ^
math/math.h:186:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_DIAG' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const float* alpha,
                                                            ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::trmm(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, DType*, int) [with DType = float]':
math/math.h:188:72: error: 'cblas_strmm' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_strmm(order, side, uplo, ta, diag, m, n, *alpha, A, lda, B, ldb);
                                                                        ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:192:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                             ^
math/math.h:192:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_SIDE' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:192:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:193:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const double* alpha,
                             ^
math/math.h:193:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_DIAG' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const double* alpha,
                                                            ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::trmm(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, DType*, int) [with DType = double]':
math/math.h:195:72: error: 'cblas_dtrmm' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_dtrmm(order, side, uplo, ta, diag, m, n, *alpha, A, lda, B, ldb);
                                                                        ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:199:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                             ^
math/math.h:199:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_SIDE' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:199:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:200:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const Complex64* alpha,
                             ^
math/math.h:200:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_DIAG' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const Complex64* alpha,
                                                            ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::trmm(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<float>]':
math/math.h:202:71: error: 'cblas_ctrmm' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_ctrmm(order, side, uplo, ta, diag, m, n, alpha, A, lda, B, ldb);
                                                                       ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:206:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                             ^
math/math.h:206:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_SIDE' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                           ^
math/math.h:206:87: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void trmm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_SIDE side, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo,
                                                                                       ^
math/math.h:207:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_TRANSPOSE' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const Complex128* alpha,
                             ^
math/math.h:207:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_DIAG' without previous declaration
                  const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE ta, const enum CBLAS_DIAG diag, const int m, const int n, const Complex128* alpha,
                                                            ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::trmm(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const DType*, const DType*, int, DType*, int) [with DType = nm::Complex<double>]':
math/math.h:209:71: error: 'cblas_ztrmm' was not declared in this scope
   cblas_ztrmm(order, side, uplo, ta, diag, m, n, alpha, A, lda, B, ldb);
                                                                       ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:540:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline int potrf(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int N, DType* A, const int lda) {
                             ^
math/math.h:540:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline int potrf(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int N, DType* A, const int lda) {
                                                           ^
math/math.h:881:30: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline void lauum(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int N, DType* A, const int lda) {
                              ^
math/math.h:881:60: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline void lauum(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int N, DType* A, const int lda) {
                                                            ^
math/math.h: In function 'void nm::math::lauum(int, int, int, DType*, int)':
math/math.h:896:17: error: 'CblasUpper' was not declared in this scope
     if (uplo == CblasUpper) {
                 ^
math/math.h:897:20: error: 'CblasRowMajor' was not declared in this scope
       if (order == CblasRowMajor) {
                    ^
math/math.h:905:20: error: 'CblasRowMajor' was not declared in this scope
       if (order == CblasRowMajor) {
                    ^
math/math.h:919:37: error: 'CblasLower' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasConjTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                     ^
math/math.h:919:50: error: 'CblasConjTrans' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasConjTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                                  ^
math/math.h:919:67: error: 'CblasNoTrans' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasConjTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                                                   ^
math/math.h:922:36: error: 'CblasLeft' was not declared in this scope
       nm::math::trmm<DType>(order, CblasLeft, uplo, CblasConjTrans, CblasNonUnit, Nright, Nleft, &ONE, U1, lda, G, lda);
                                    ^
math/math.h:922:69: error: 'CblasNonUnit' was not declared in this scope
       nm::math::trmm<DType>(order, CblasLeft, uplo, CblasConjTrans, CblasNonUnit, Nright, Nleft, &ONE, U1, lda, G, lda);
                                                                     ^
math/math.h:925:37: error: 'CblasLower' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                     ^
math/math.h:925:50: error: 'CblasTrans' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                                  ^
math/math.h:925:63: error: 'CblasNoTrans' was not declared in this scope
                             uplo == CblasLower ? CblasTrans : CblasNoTrans,
                                                               ^
math/math.h:928:36: error: 'CblasLeft' was not declared in this scope
       nm::math::trmm<DType>(order, CblasLeft, uplo, CblasTrans, CblasNonUnit, Nright, Nleft, &ONE, U1, lda, G, lda);
                                    ^
math/math.h:928:65: error: 'CblasNonUnit' was not declared in this scope
       nm::math::trmm<DType>(order, CblasLeft, uplo, CblasTrans, CblasNonUnit, Nright, Nleft, &ONE, U1, lda, G, lda);
                                                                 ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:969:37: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_lauum(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                     ^
math/math.h:969:67: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_lauum(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                                                   ^
math/math.h: In function 'int nm::math::clapack_lauum(int, int, int, void*, int)':
math/math.h:973:15: error: 'CblasUpper' was not declared in this scope
   if (uplo == CblasUpper) lauum<is_complex, DType>(order, uplo, n, reinterpret_cast<DType*>(a), lda);
               ^
math/math.h: At global scope:
math/math.h:1016:37: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_potrf(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                     ^
math/math.h:1016:67: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_potrf(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                                                   ^
math/math.h:1023:29: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline int potri(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, DType* a, const int lda) {
                             ^
math/math.h:1023:59: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline int potri(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, DType* a, const int lda) {
                                                           ^
math/math.h:1060:37: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_ORDER' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_potri(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                     ^
math/math.h:1060:67: error: use of enum 'CBLAS_UPLO' without previous declaration
 inline int clapack_potri(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO uplo, const int n, void* a, const int lda) {
                                                                   ^
In file included from nmatrix.cpp:297:0:
ruby_nmatrix.c: In function 'VALUE nm_reshape_bang(VALUE, VALUE)':
ruby_nmatrix.c:1069:11: warning: unused variable 'elem' [-Wunused-variable]
     void* elem = s->elements;
           ^
make: *** [nmatrix.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nmatrix-0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/nmatrix-0.1.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Can you try to install the individual gem that you're looking for and see if it works?

Comment: @SameerDeshmukh I am new to all this. What all gems would I need to plot graphs? Let me know. I would install them manually

Comment: @SameerDeshmukh but as you said I did installed these gems `gems install pry-doc awesome_print gnuplot rubyvis nyaplot  iruby`

Comment: You need nyaplot or gnuplotrb for plotting.

Comment: Regarding the error, it's most probably that you need atlas and lapack installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As suggested by Sameer Deshmukh,*

Install the gems what you wish to use. I am listing all the gems here from SciRuby website

> Visualization: rubyvis, plotrb
>
> Statistics and Probability: statsample, distribution
>
> Numeric: minimization, integration, nmatrix

Installation for every gem is quite simple as you would have guessed

```
$ gem install <name-of-the-gem>
```

I would suggest visit [SciRuby](https://github.com/SciRuby) on Github read about every gem there and install them with there dependencies